# Export UIImageView layers to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView with a layer on top of it and I want to save the UIImageView.image with those layers.

Example:

```
imageView.layer.mask = someLayer

let image = imageView.image

let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But this only saves the Image without the layers from the imageView. What do I have to do?

Taking a screenshot of the imageView may be nice but I lose image quality while doing this and I want to keep the original resolution.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the original resolution:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromImageView:(UIImageView *)view{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this. The resolution is ok but if you zoom in and compare it to the original one it is still less. Is there no way to transfer the imageView mask?